# Working with files in scala 2.11._

Tags: file, io, scala-2.11

What's the best way to work with the file system (read-write-delete-copy file operations) in scala 2.11 ? I used to use scalax.file._, but it was removed.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you can use java.nio.file. It provides a convenient way to do read-write-delete-copy file operations.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/package-summary.html

Comment: Thanks, best results!